# How to disable validation with regex validator cannot type 0 after 0

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have scenario for validation number like this:

```
000...
```

this not allowed because `0` have been entered in first.

So how to disable entered `0` after `0` in first but for this `01000` etc it's ok.

Comment: What about `00100`? Is that allowed?

Comment: actualy it's for validation phone number area not for real numeric. in my country phone number area of resident usualy like "021" or "0632" or "020". i hope you understand Thanks.

Comment: 00100 it's not allowed it's must 0100

Answer (score 4):

So you want to allow one leading zero but not more?

```
^(?!00)\d+$
```

matches any integer number that doesn't start with `00`. It does allow a single `0` (but it also allows a number that does not contain any `0`).

If you want to allow any number except `0` or `00` or `00000` etc., use

```
^(?!0+$)\d+$
```

If you want to *require* exactly one `0` at the start (which makes sense for telephone area codes in many locales), use

```
^0(?!0)\d+$
```

Comment: It's work.. but i need user cannot type 0 in second so it's not show after 0 in first. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
^0[1-9][0-9]*$
```

this allows numbers which

1. must start with '0'
2. must contain another digit excluded '0'
3. contains only digits after the 1st and the 2nd

Moreover, if you want to trim for phone number prefixes (like in italy they vary from 2 to 4 digits, remove the last `*` and replace with `{0-2}` (this works in java for sure, i don't know if it is still valid in other formats but there will be something similar for sure)

```
^0[1-9][0-9]{0-2}$
```